# Flask Socket-IO - Realtime Chat Application, Sockets not working like they should

Tags: javascript, python, flask, socket.io, flask-socketio

I have been working on this flask project for a while now and have begun using Flask-SocketIO in combination with Javascript SocketIO in order to make a real-time messaging feature.

Here is the python portion of the code

```py
## Socket IO for messaging
socketio = SocketIO(app, async_mode='gevent')

def messageReceived(methods=['GET', 'POST']):
    print("Message Received")

@socketio.on('message')
def handle_message(json, methods=['GET', 'POST']):
    sender = current_user.id
    message_content = request.form.get('message')
    conversation_id = id
    today = date.today()
    time_sent = today.strftime("%B %d, %Y")

    message = Message(conversation_id=conversation_id, sender=sender, message_content=message_content, time_sent=time_sent)

    db.session.add(message)
    db.session.commit()

    print('received my event: ' + str(json))
    socketio.emit('my response', json, callback=messageReceived)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    socketio.run(app, debug=True)
```

And below is the Javascript portion

```js
  var socket = io.connect('http://'+document.domain+':'+location.port+'/conversations/1');
      
        socket.on('connect', function() {
          socket.emit('message', {
            data: 'User Connected'
          } )
          $('#messageForm').on( 'submit', function( e ) {
            e.preventDefault()
            let user_input = $('#messagecontent').val()
            socket.emit('message', {
              message : user_input
            } )
            $('#messagecontent').val( '' ).focus()
          } )
        } )
        socket.on('my response', function( msg ) {
          console.log(msg)
            $('#messages').append('<div class="message-received"><p class="message-request-username message-rec">'+ msg.message +'</p></div>' )
        })
```

The issue I am having is that either the Javascript or the Python is not running correctly as when I submit the Form the page refreshes and nothing happens, no message is displayed and no information is being added to my database, why is this? and Can anyone offer a solution?

This is being repeated while the app runs in my terminal
[image: Imgur]

Browser console as requested by a user in the comments
[image: Imgur2]

**I will happily edit the question if any further information is required.**

Comment: As you mentioned page getting refreshed, it means the form submit event handler is not getting bound. You have put this $('#messageForm').on( 'submit' ... inside the socket on connect event handler. So either your browser couldn't connect to socket server or the id messageForm is wrong. Try putting alert() or console.logs in js code

Comment: @Raihanul it would appear the socket connection is not successful, can you offer any fixes?

Comment: Firstly, you're trying to connect to /conversations/1. But I don't see this anywhere in your flask code. Secondly, specifying http:// host:port.. means you're making a CORS request (which I also can't see in your flask socket configuration). Try var socket = io();

Comment: @Raihanul That did not solve the issue.

Comment: What do you see in the browser console?

Comment: @Raihanul I will update the question with the screenshot. But it isn't anything major

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/233992/discussion-between-raihanul-and-mattmccann).

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure this is your only problem, but this is definitely wrong:

> when I submit the Form the page refreshes and nothing happens

If I understand this correctly, you are submitting a form in your application. A form submission will destroy the current page, with all of its network connections. Your Socket.IO connection will go away during the form submission.

When working with Socket.IO your form submissions need to be made as background requests, so that the page does not go away.